split with multiple delimiters sql
I have a use case where i need to split strings by multiple delimiters.



client_id




blah_blah


bleh-bleh



select client_id ,split(client_id,'-')[0] col1` ,split(client_id,'-')[1] col2 from mytbl

returns



Client_id
col1
col2




bleh-bleh
bleh
bleh



I have been trying various permutations to get two delimiters in with no success.
select client_id ,split(client_id,'-'||'_')[0] col1` ,split(client_id,'-'||'_')[1] col2 from mytbl

this errors out, but what i want to return is...



client_id
col1
col2




blah-blah
blah
blah


bleh_bleh
bleh
bleh




You can use the regexp_split_to_array with a delimiter regex that is either a dash or an underscore:
select 
    client_id,
    (regexp_split_to_array(client_id, '[-_]'))[1] col1, 
    (regexp_split_to_array(client_id, '[-_]'))[2] col2 
    from mytbl;

Here is a fiddle POC: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/13029

It's syntactically wrong in two ways: regular PostgreSQL arrays are 1-based, so [0] will just get you a null, and you need to wrap the call in parentheses to be able to subscript the resulting array with square brackets, to avoid another syntax error. The fiddle you linked does not demonstrate the code you propose - I'm unsure why you didn't just test your solution there.

Thanks for the feedback @Zegarek - updated the snippet and fiddle with the full solution rather than just the POC of using regexp_split_to_array

Thanks for addressing the remark. It's good that you tested and fixed the validity of the code you proposed, but you're not addressing performance: you're weighing things down with the regex and array overheads. Still, with the problems fixed, if the performance is sufficient to OP, the solution is as good as any - after all they don't need a sports car to get from A to B.

You can do that exactly how you planned, as long as you translate() all the alternative delimiters to the one you want to use: demo
select client_id
  , split_part(client_id2,'-',1)
  , split_part(client_id2,'-',2)
from mytbl cross join lateral
(values(translate(client_id,'_;/','---'))) as v(client_id2)




client_id
split_part
split_part




blah_blah
blah
blah


bleh-bleh
bleh
bleh



Nice thing about this approach is that it simply runs faster compared to the regex+array ideas. Demo shows this one's 3x faster on 10k-300k random samples, thanks to being free from the performance penalty that comes with regex and array overheads.

Simple Solution in Databricks (As your question has a tag of Databricks)
select
  client_id,
  split(client_id, '-|_')[0] col1,
  split(client_id, '-|_')[1] col2
from
  mytbl

